# Rasa nlu server problem with the error 500 and parsing

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

I started the nlu server by typing this command in cmd:

```
    rasa run --enable-api -m models/(name of my package).tar
```

and then in other cmd window typed:

```
    curl localhost:5005/model/parse -d ‘{“text”:“hello”}’
```

after that I got an error:

```
    {“version”:“1.2.3”,“status”:“failure”,“message”:“An unexpected error 
    occurred. Error: Failed when parsing body as 
    json”,“reason”:“ParsingError”,“details”:{},“help”:null,“code”:500}
```

What is the reason for it? what should I change to get the normal(200) output?

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate problem! Please look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569758/rasa-nlu-server-failure/57867760#57867760

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this and see whether it works.

```
rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors ‘*’ --debug
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately, it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

CURL POST Request (Mac and Ubuntu):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST -d '{"sender":"y1mLd","message":"hi"}' http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook
```

Note : for windows you need to remove the quotes

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST -d {"sender":"y1mLd","message":"hi"} http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook
```

Output

```
[{"recipient_id":"y1mLd","text":"Welcome, Please let me know how I could be a help today!"}]
```