# Rasa nlu server failure

Tags: node.js, rasa-nlu, rasa

I started the rasa server by typing this command in cmd:

```
  rasa run --enable-api -m models/(my_model).tar.gz --cors "*" --debug
```

I put this command in another cmd:

```
  curl -X POST localhost:5005/model/parse -d '{"text":"hello"}'
```

After that I got this error:

```
  {"version":"1.2.2","status":"failure","message":"An unexpected error occurred. Error: Failed when parsing body as json","reason":"ParsingError","details":{},"help":null,"code":500}
```

Any help? How can I integrate Rasa with Node.js?

Comment: what does the server log from the `rasa run` command show? you might also need to set the json header in your curl request: `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST -d '{"sender":"y1mLd","message":"hi"}' http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook
```

Output would be

```
[{"recipient_id":"y1mLd","text":"Welcome, Please let me know how I could be a help today!"}]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simple curl without method type worked for me:

```
curl localhost:5005/model/parse -d '{"text":"hello"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error on Windows 10 . Following commands worked for me finally.

```
curl localhost:5005/model/parse -d "{\"text\":\"hello\"}"
```

and

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:5005/model/parse -d "{\"text\":\"hello\"}"
```